# AWS SQS and SNS with .NET core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I want to implement a publish/subscribe system inside my Micro service application on top of .NET CORE, and since I've everything built on top of AWS, I started to check SQS.

But from what I understood, SQS is only a queue that doesn't offer me that possibility, so yes I can send and read messages to the queue, but I can't have my clients consuming in real time based on topic and sending messages to every client that is subscribing to that topic, right? That's why they have SNS.

From what I understand in order to use SNS, we will always need to have SQS too, but what I'm not finding is how can I integrate SNS on .NET Core? Is there a good tutorial? Because for SQS there's plenty, but for SNS I'm not finding much.

Comment: Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/sns-apis-intro.html & try some sample code  - also, no actually! While they are commonly used together, one is not needed for the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"I'm not finding is how can I integrate SNS on .NET"**

There is a brand new AWS tutorial (only a few days old) that shows how to use the **AWS.NET API** to create an MVC .NET app that uses the .NET SNS API to write a pub/sub app. This example uses .NET async calls as well.

[image]

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/cross-service/SubscribePublishTranslate

Comment: the link is not working

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you should be looking at a combination of SQS and SNS.

SQS lacks pub/sub and SNS lacks [competing consumers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers).

NServiceBus provides all of the middleware needed to work with both of these underlying services correctly and safely, and in .net core. Here's a simple sample: https://docs.particular.net/samples/sqs/simple/

For more information on how it works, check out the docs:
https://docs.particular.net/transports/sqs/